# Meteor JS - Client Collection seems to be empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Its been a long time since I used Meteor or dabbled in the UI world for that matter, so forgive me if this is poor question.

api/main.js:

```
export const Nodes = new Meteor.Collection("nodes");
export const Links = new Meteor.Collection("links");
```

server/main.js

```
import { Links, Nodes } from '../api/main.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
}

Meteor.methods({
  traverseDocument: function traverseDocument(documentKey) {
    // ... do stuff ...
    Links.insert( data.links );
    Nodes.insert( data.nodes );
    return data;
  }
}
```

client/main.js

```
import { Links, Nodes } from '../api/main.js';
import './main.html';

Meteor.startup(function () {
  // Fetch data via a call
  Meteor.call("traverseDocument", 'NTD000000228506', function (error, results) {});
});

Template.viz.rendered = function () {
  console.log(Nodes.find());                 // <-- LocalConnection.Cursor()
  console.log(Nodes.find().fetch());         // <-- This is empty []
  console.log(Nodes._collection._docs._map); // <-- This returns Object{}
}
```

I've tried:
 1. Publish/Subscribe
 2. I tried a helper function
 3. I Have moved the Meteor.Call() into the client startup function

So this now seems to be closer to working.

The original question changes now to - Why does the find().fetch() return an empty array ?

Maybe I should post a new question and mark this one as fixed ?

Comment: I smell a timing problem. In your last code sample, `console.log()` executes *immediately* after `Meteor.call()`. That means it executes long before the `function (error, results) {}` callback will even run. Try moving the logging into the callback.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does seem like a timing problem, so I tried moving the Meteor.call() to an onCreated event but still no luck. I also tried subscribing and other things, but still no joy.

Comment: Did you `Meteor.publish()` your two collections on the server?

Comment: I did try the Meteor.publish() but it didnt seem to work. I just moved the Meteor.call() into the client startup and it looks like Nodes collection now gets populated. However the fetch() seems to be strange.

Nodes.find() returns a LocalConnection.Cursor() but when I add a .fetch() on the end, all I get is an empty array.

console.log(Nodes._collection._docs._map) returns an Object{} but feels a bit nasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save value of results from callback to session variable or reactive variable and then retrieve later.

```
import { Links, Nodes } from '../api/main.js';
import './main.html';

Template.viz.rendered = function () {
  Meteor.call("traverseDocument", 'VALUE001', function (error, results) {
    if(error) {
      // handle error
    }
    else {
     Session.set('result',results);  // save result in session or reactive       variable
    }
    console.log(Nodes);  // <-- This works, has data
  });

  if(Session.get('result') {
  console.log(Session.get('result')); // <-- Retrieve value from session or reactive var
 }
}
```

Comment: After some frigging around, this now works nice and cleanly! Many thanks.